# How to create NamedPipe as LocalSystem account that can be connected to by normal users

Tags: c, windows, named-pipes

I am able to create a NamedPipe on Windows that clients can connect to and everything works fine, but when I create the pipe as LocalSystem user, my "normal" users cannot connect to it anymore (accessDenied, lastError=5)

I already tried to create a security descriptor from this String:

```
            String secDesc = "D:"+
                    "(D;OICI;GA;;;BG)"+     // Deny access to built-in guests
                    "(D;OICI;GA;;;AN)"+     // Deny access to anonymous logon
                    "(A;OICI;GRGWGX;;;AU)"; // Allow read/write/execute to authenticated users
```

and use the convertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor function in Windows to build one, but still no success. Anyone here that can help me with that? Do I need another security descriptor, or can I work around that mess somehow else?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I needed another descriptor so the low privilegued user account could access the pipe:

```
            String secDesc = "S:(ML;;NWNR;;;LW)"+ // Some other stuff I know nothing about
                    "D:"+
                    "(D;OICI;GA;;;BG)"+     // Deny access to built-in guests
                    "(D;OICI;GA;;;AN)"+     // Deny access to anonymous logon
                    "(A;OICI;GRGWGX;;;AU)"; // Allow read/write/execute to authenticated users
```